# Re-dress a ST monad as something similar to the State monad

Tags: haskell, ffi, state-monad, st-monad

Here's the scenario: Given is a C library, with some struct at its core and operations thereon provided by an abundance of C functions.

**Step 1:** Using Haskell's [FFI](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface) a wrapper is created. It has functions like `myCLibInit :: IO MyCLibObj`, `myCLibOp1 :: MyCLibObj -> ... -> IO ()`, and so on. `MyCLibObj` is an opaque type that carries (and hides) a `Ptr` or `ForeignPtr` to the actual C struct, for example as shown in this [wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/FFI_cook_book#Passing_opaque_structures.2Ftypes) or in [RWH ch. 17](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/interfacing-with-c-the-ffi.html).

**Step 2:** Using `unsafeIOToST` from [`Control.Monad.ST.Unsafe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST-Unsafe.html) convert all the `IO` actions into [`ST`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST-Safe.html#t:ST) actions. This is done by introducing something like

```
 data STMyCLib s = STMyCLib MyCLibObj
```

and then wrapping all `IO` functions in `ST` functions, for example:

```
myCLibInit' :: ST s (STMyCLib s)
myCLibInit' = unsafeIOToST $ STMyCLib <$> myCLibInit
```

This allows to write imperative-style programs that mirror the use of the OO-like C library, e.g.:

```
doSomething :: ST s Bool
doSomething = do
    obj1 <- myCLibInit'
    success1 <- myCLibOp1' obj1 "some-other-input"
    ...
    obj2 <- myCLibInit'
    result <- myCLibOp2' obj2 42
    ...
    return True   -- or False

main :: IO ()
main = do
    ...
    let success = runST doSomething
    ...
```

**Step 3:** Often it doesn't make sense to mingle operations on several `MyCLibObj` in one do-block. For example when the C struct is (or should be thought of as) a singleton instance. Doing something like in `doSomething` above is either nonsensical, or just plain forbidden (for example, when the C struct is a `static`). In this case language resembling the one of the [`State`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html) monad is necessary:

```
doSomething :: ResultType
doSomething =  withMyCLibInstance $ do
    success <- myCLibOp1'' "some-other-input"
    result <- myCLibOp2'' 42
    ...
    return result
```

where

```
withMyCLibInstance :: Q a -> a
```

And this leads to the **question**: How can the `ST s a` monad be re-dressed as something that resembles more the `State` monad. Since `withMyCLibInstance` would use the `runST` function the new monad, let's call it `Q` (for 'q'uestion), should be

```
newtype Q a = Q (forall s. ST s a)
```

This looks thoroughly weird to me. I'm already struggling with implementing the `Functor` instance for this `Q`, let alone `Applicative` and `Monad`. [`ST s`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.ST.html#line-72) actually is a monad, already, but state `s` mustn't escape the `ST` monad, hence the `forall s. ST s a`. It's the only way to get rid of the `s` because `runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a`, and `withMyCLibInstance` is just a `myCLibInit'` followed by a `runST`. But somehow this doesn't fit.

What is the right way to tackle step 3? Should I even do step 2, or roll my `Q` right after step 1? My sense is that this should be quite simple. The `ST` monad has all I need, the `Q` just needs to be set up the right way...

**Update 1:** The singleton and static struct examples in step 3 are not very good. If two such do blocks were executed in parallel, very bad things might happen, i.e. both do blocks would work on the same C struct in parallel.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use `withMyCLibInstance :: (forall s. Q s a) -> a`, and modify `Q` accordingly? It seems you are trying to hide the `s` parameter, which is necessary for `ST` to work.

Comment: I'm not quite able to put together a solution based on your suggestion. In the end, there must be some monad `M` such that `withMyCLibInstance :: M a -> a`, so do we not end up with `newtype M a = forall s. ST s a`?

Comment: Why do you need a separate monad? Can you just write `withMyCLibInstance :: (forall s. STMyClib s -> ST s a) -> a` instead and not expose `myCLibInit`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, that would lead to something like `withMyCLibInstance $ \obj -> do ...`. Ok, that's a step forward. I still would have to use the `obj` inside the `do` all the time, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a reader effect to access a singleton, instantiating it only in the `run` function:

```
newtype MyCLibST s a = MyCLibST { unMyCLibST :: ReaderT (STMyCLib s) (ST s) a }

runMyCLibST :: (forall s. MyCLibST s a) -> a
runMyCLibST m = runST (myCLibInit >>= runReaderT (unMyCLibST m))

-- Wrap the API with this.
unsafeMkMyCLibST :: (MyCLibObj -> IO a) -> MyCLibST s a
```

`s` should appear as a parameter to `MyCLibST` if you want to keep access to other `ST` features like mutable references and arrays.

Comment: `ReaderT`... that's a very good point. Why not use the simpler `type MyCLibST a = forall s. ReaderT (STMyCLib s) (ST s) a`?

Comment: Type synonyms with quantifiers have various problems: they make type inference difficult, Haskell's type system is not impredicative (`[MyCLibST a]` is not a valid type) and `MyCLibST` is no `Monad` (because type synonyms must always be fully applied). As for the question of `type`  vs `newtype`, it's mostly a matter of taste, but while `type` makes code reuse easier, `newtype` enables better defined abstraction boundaries. I think `newtype` is the safer default.